# Hadoop MapReduce: Is it possible to only use a fraction of the input data as the input to a MR job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My input data's key class is `WritableComparable` and it is present in the form of `MapFile`s. Is there some way to set a minimum and maximum key and have only records transferred to the Mappers whose keys are between these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not possible.** Because for a map-reduce job we simply specifies the input.

One thing we can do is, writing a condition in mapper. if key is b/w min & max value, then only process key-value pair & emit output to reducer. Otherwise, simply do nothing. But even in this case, our map phase is processing on all of the input, but reduce phase will be only on the key range we have specified.

**A better way**:
When a map-reduce job is run on a given input, first input will be split by [InputSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html) such that each split's data will be processed by one mapper. But map() method expects one record at a time as key-value pair. It is the responsibility of [RecordReader](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html) of the job to process this and present a record-oriented view.

Customize the RecordReader of your job, and override [getCurrentKey()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html#getCurrentKey()) method, such that if key is b/w min & max return the current key else return null.

By Doing this, only fraction of the input data whose keys are in given range will be sent to the map method.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that too. Would it also make sense if I overrode the getSplits method to return just fitting InputSplits or does this make no difference in speed?

Comment: I think It doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Ok I just thought because filtering in the RecordReader would still iterate over the whole data, thus slowing down the input data sent to the mappers and moving the bottleneck one step up. What do you think of the idea reading the first and last key of the Split and just returning nothing when the interval is out of range?

Comment: Okay. You mean to say, Instead of filtering based on each record, you can directly filter out some splits(if key is out of range). This should work!!! Good point!!!

Comment: I just tried this and it works. I now check the input splits at the very beginning and discard everything if they do not match. For the ones that do match, I use your suggested approach customizing the `getCurrentKey()` method.